# vue3 pinia vue3-openlayers turf.js getting console errors using values from store or props

Tags: vuejs3, pinia, vue-props, turfjs, vue3-openlayers

I am converting a project from Vue2 to Vue3 using pinia and <script setup>. The project uses vue3-openlayers.

I have my map working:

```html
<ol-map :loadTilesWhileAnimating="true" :loadTilesWhileInteracting="true" style="height: 90%; width: 100%"
        data-projection="EPSG:4326" :projection="projection">
        <ol-view ref="view" :center="centerOfMap" :rotation="rotation" :zoom.sync="zoom" :projection="projection" />

        <ol-tile-layer>
          <ol-source-osm />
        </ol-tile-layer>

        <ol-vector-layer>
          <ol-source-vector>
            <!--This gives us the center pin -->
            <ol-feature>
              <ol-geom-point :coordinates="[-309812.55518814427, 6929102.511332245]"></ol-geom-point>
              <ol-style>
                <ol-style-circle radius="5">
                  <ol-style-fill color="red"></ol-style-fill>
                  <ol-style-stroke color="red" width="2"></ol-style-stroke>
                </ol-style-circle>
                <ol-style-icon :src="purplePinIcon" :anchor="[0.25, 0.9]" :scale="0.07"></ol-style-icon>
              </ol-style>
            </ol-feature>
            . . . 
          </ol-source-vector>
        </ol-vector-layer>
      </ol-map>
```

and this centers the map and puts in a pin as expected. I would like to add more pins to the map which come from object in the store.

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from '../stores/store.js'
import * as turf from '@turf/turf'

import purplePin from '../assets/purple-pin.png'


//const props = defineProps(['ActiveEvent'])
const purplePinIcon = purplePin
const store = useStore()
const ActiveEvent = computed(() => store.ActiveEvent)
. . . more stuff including the functions geometry() and convertToMercator()
</script>
```

When I add the following html block to the map

```html
            <ol-feature v-for="(S, idx) in ActiveEvent.SellersList" :key="idx">
              <ol-geom-point :coordinates="convertToMercator(S.Latitude, S.Longlitude)"> </ol-geom-point>
              <ol-style-circle radius="5">
                <!-- <ol-style-fill color="white"></ol-style-fill>
                <ol-style-stroke color="red"></ol-style-stroke> -->
              </ol-style-circle>
              <ol-style-icon :src="purplePinIcon" :anchor="[0.25, 0.9]" :scale="0.07"></ol-style-icon>
            </ol-feature>
```

I get a console error:

```
vue3-openlayers.es.js:49236 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
```

I know the ActivEvent is being read and is properly reactive because I see the values if I add the following code (outside of the ol-map)

```html
    <div v-for="(S, idx) in ActiveEvent.SellersList" :key="idx">

      <h3>{{ idx }}</h3>
      <pre>{{ S }} , {{ convertToMercator(S.Latitude, S.Longlitude) }}</pre>
      <hr />

    </div>
```

I have tried reading ActiveEvent from the store and passing it in as a prop from the parent component which also uses the store.ActiveEvent and neither are working for me.  How do I make the ol-feature reactive, or wait for the ActiveEvent to be available before rendering.  I have also tried v-if="ActiveEvent" on the ol-feature and v-cloak on the div that surrounds the map to prevent rendering until the ActiveEvent is loaded with no joy.  I've been on this for 2 days now and I am sure it will be a 5 minute fix, but any help is much appreciated.  For context there is nothing wrong with the geometry() or convertToMercator() functions, they both render proper data sets outside of the map. **Additional: If the SellersList is an empty array, then I don't get the error.  Don't know if that helps, but it definately feels like it is an issue reading the array elements.**

Edits - As per requests in the comments: convertToMercator is jsut a wrapper around the turf function.  My data is coming in as KML which is lat/long and turf wants long/lat.

```js
function convertToMercator(lat, long) {
  let x = turf.toMercator([long, lat])
  console.log("Mercator Value: ", x)
  return x
}
```

SellersList is just an array of lat/long coordinates

```js
[{"Latitude":52.7122145235652,"Longlitude":-2.77611455052844},{"Latitude":52.7122145235652,"Longlitude":-2.77611455052844},{"Latitude":52.705886,"Longlitude":-2.779051},{"Latitude":52.705886,"Longlitude":-2.779051}]
```

I think the issue may actually be with turf and when the calculations are trying to run, rather than the mapping. This works:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ turf.point([parseFloat(long), parseFloat(lat)]) }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from '../stores/store.js'
import * as turf from '@turf/turf'

const store = useStore()
const ActiveEvent = computed(() => store.ActiveEvent)

let lat = ref(52.7076467374228)
let long = ref(-2.78309353537633)

</script>
```

It returns

```js
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -2.78309353537633,
      52.7076467374228
    ]
  }
}
```

If I change the variables from being hard assigned to coming from a variable (in this case the store.ActiveEvent.lat)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ turf.point([parseFloat(long), parseFloat(lat)]) }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from '../stores/store.js'
import * as turf from '@turf/turf'

const store = useStore()
const ActiveEvent = computed(() => store.ActiveEvent)

let lat = ref(ActiveEvent.lat) // <-- This is different
let long = ref(-2.78309353537633)

</script>
```

I get an error in the console

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: coordinates must contain numbers
```

and the component tries to remount 50x a second....  I have tried

```
let lat = ActiveEvent.lat
let lat = computed(() => ActiveEvent.lat)
let lat = ref(ActiveEvent.lat)
```

I have tried setting the values in the onMounted and onBeforeMount hooks with no success.  What I need is to defer the calculations until the data has loaded.  Any ideas?

Comment: The shared code is not sufficient for reproducing the error. One would need to look at the relevant store state/getters as well as the data structure being used, as well as package versions. Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] if you want *my* help, using codesandbox's [import](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) or similar.

Comment: Note `'pinia'` provides `storeToRefs` (e.g: `const { ActiveEvent } = storeToRefs(useStore())`), but I do not think replacing your `computed()` with this will fix the issue, because they're equivalent syntaxes. I try to stay clear of guesswork, especially on [SO].

Comment: At the very least, provide the contents of `convertToMercator` and the complete data structure of an `ActiveEvent.SellersList` element.